# How to include a phtml file into CMS page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cms

This is the code equivalent in magento 1

```
{{block type="core/template" template="theme/home_banner.phtml"  name="myname"}}
```

Which is the equivalent code for magento 2.
I try to include my phtml in this Path: ?.

```
C:\xampp2\htdocs\myProject\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Special_Price\special_price.phtml
```

I' am opened for any ideas.
Thank you!

Comment: pls check my answer

Answer (score 4):

Calling in `blocks or cms pages`

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="myname" template="Magento_Theme::theme/home_banner.phtml"}}
```

Comment: But where should i put exactly my phtml file if i am usig Luma theme?

Comment: put file inside theme-frontend-luma/xyz any related folder and define path 
template="Magento_Theme::xyzfolder/home_banner.phtml @AlinLupoiu

Comment: the code that you gave me it is recognized as a html code!